# Experience Analytics stopped working with error related to Sitecore.Analytics.OmniChannel

Tags: sitecore9

Experience Analytics stopped working and it's now not showing any interaction. Upon checking logs I found the below exception but I am not able to find any working solution for this .I need your suggestion on this if any one had faced similar type of issues requesting you to please help me

ERROR [Experience Analytics]: SegmentProcessor failed to process interaction '00d87833-db45-0000-0000-05d25540e158' segment '2db07a51-fad7-4ede-b727-bd49ebb9d6f2' - DescriptorId : 2f421912-f1b3-49d8-82b8-50a64c80e4e3
Sitecore.XConnect.Segmentation.ExpressionBuilder.PredicateDescriptorException: No known predicate type could be determined from 'Sitecore.Analytics.OmniChannel.Conditions.Channel.CurrentInteractionIsOnChannelCondition,Sitecore.Analytics.OmniChannel' specified in the definition item (Id = '2f421912-f1b3-49d8-82b8-50a64c80e4e3', db = 'master') : Could not load type 'Sitecore.Analytics.OmniChannel.Conditions.Channel.CurrentInteractionIsOnChannelCondition' from assembly 'Sitecore.Analytics.OmniChannel'

Here the DescriptorId is a sitecore rule located at the path /sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Definitions/Elements/Channel/Current Interaction is on channel condition

I am using Sitecore 9.1 /sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Definitions/Elements/Channel/Current Interaction is on channel condition

I haven't made any changes to the above system item and there is no customization has been made.

Any suggestions please

Comment: Have you found a resolution for this?  I am seeing a similar error.  Thanks.

Comment: Not yet, We will try to reach sitecore on this. If you find anything please do let me know here

Comment: @Jon: Have you been able to get a resolution for this?